# jQuery UI Won't Hide an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I'm trying to create a jQuery slide effect so that when the button is pressed, the first paragraph tag moves out and the second paragraph tag moves into the viewport. I am using jQuery UI for the slide effects and I just can't seem to hide the second paragraph and then slide it in, in turn hiding the first paragraph.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <button onclick="hideme()">Hide it</button>
    <p id="1">Hide this text</p>
    <p id="2"> Show this text</p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#2').fadeOut(1);
});

function hideme(){
    $('#1').hide( "slide", 2000 );
    $('#2').show( "slide", 2000);
}
```

Comment: You should not have your IDs starting with number.

Comment: Please select a correct answer if it works for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#2').fadeOut(1);

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $('#1').hide("slide", 2000);
        $('#2').show("slide", 2000);
    });
});
```

This uses jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind the `click` event and it executes when the DOM is ready to be manipulated using `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/VEY2B/

Comment: I've tried to port over all the code from jsfiddle but I can't seem to get it to do anything?

Comment: @user2855971 - you still need to include links to jquery and jquery ui, are they still included in your code?

Comment: Here is the example I am trying to get it to work with but I'm having no luck, your code works perfectly otherwise, it just seems to be this example: http://jsfiddle.net/R9nGM/4/

Comment: @user2855971 - ok, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/R9nGM/6/ - I've removed the `#hidden` wrapper and added the `.show()` to the `.hide()` callback so the elements don't jump.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#text-2').fadeOut(2000);
    $('#hide-it-button').click(function() {

        $('#text-1').hide( "slide", 2000, function() {
            $('#text-2').show( "slide", 2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It fails to do anything then.

Comment: you're using .hide() and .show() incorrectly. please post your code on jsfiddle, so i can see how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

window.load may not be the best time to bind the jquery action listeners to the button. I re-wrote it as this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gyJPc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#2').fadeOut(5);

    $('button').click(function(){
        hideme();
    });

    var hideme = function(){
        $('#1').hide();
        $('#2').show();
    };
});
```